# When can 'alongside' be used to express parallelism between objects?

Tags: prepositions

Are the cars depicted in the first two scenes below parked **alongside** the wall?

[image]

[image]

If yes, let's suppose that all cars except one have gone away. Are the cars depicted in the scenes below still parked **alongside** the wall?

[image]

[image]

If not, what preposition do you use to describe the last two situations? And, is there a minimum number of cars under which you no longer use **alongside**?

Answer (score 3):

I would say the top pictures show vehicles parked *alongside* a wall, but the bottom pictures show vehicles parked *against* the wall.

I would use the same prepositions if there was one car or many cars. From the top, then, I see:

- 7 cars alongside a wall,
- 12 cars against a wall,
- 1 car parked alongside a wall, and
- 1 car parked against the wall.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/against) definition #8 for *against* reads:

> **against** next to; adjoining ⇒ *the house against the church*

If one didn't like *against* for some reason, an alternative would be ***perpendicular to***:

- *There are 12 cars parked perpendicular to the wall*.

Finally, one could use *along* in place of *alongside*:

- *There is one car parked along the wall*.

Comment: J.R., and, do you see 12 cars parked *along against* the wall, too?

Comment: No, I would only use one preposition in this context.